# How should I implement the RadioGroup?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, radio-button, android-xml

I have this layout which asks for 2 options and you have to choose one of them, so we need to use RadioGroup there but each RadioButton has a Text and an Image inside of it, I looked up overlapping images in RadioButton and doing it through a selector (drawable) but I was unable to.

**Layout File:**

[image]

Comment: I think not use `RadioGroup ` is better. just make click event each.

Comment: no but I want the user to select only one of the two

Comment: You can handle that by click events  toggling other when selected

Comment: can you share some reference?

Comment: Why do you need to use RadioGroup rather than just changing the state of the other button when one is clicked?

Comment: how does that work?

Answer (score 0):

how about make RadioButton using drawableTop to show the icon?

```
 <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/rad_home"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/rad_background"
    android:button="@null"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/home_icon"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Home"
    android:textColor="@drawable/text_background"
    android:textSize="@dimen/rad_text_size" >
```